# Azure PowerShell - Not recognizing resource group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

**Question**: Why I am getting the following error in the last line of `powershell` script shown below - and how can we fix the error? I have double checked by copying/pasting the `resource group (RG)` name from Azure Portal to verify that the RG name is correct:

> Get-AzStorageAccount: Resource group 'rg-e-testdataanalytics-dev-01' could not be found

```
# these are for the storage account to be used
$resourceGroup = "rg-e-testdataanalytics-dev-01"
$storageAccountName = "myStorageAccount"

# get a reference to the storage account
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you might be in wrong Azure Context. To verify this run the command `Get-AzContext`, which will return the [*Active Directory account, Active Directory tenant, Azure subscription, and the targeted Azure environment*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azcontext?view=azps-10.0.0#description).

*Azure Resource Manager cmdlets use these settings by default when making Azure Resource Manager requests*. So make sure you are in correct Active Directory account/Active Directory tenant/Azure subscription/Azure environment.

If you are in wrong subscription, you can set the [subscription context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-10.0.0#example-1-set-the-subscription-context) by

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```